# which jquery event could help me better (onclick, hover ?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events

I have a dilema

In my website, I need to get the value of a span which is contained in a modal
when the modal is opened the value of it change.
When it is not it contain the old value
It is the value of the cart in my online shop
when I click add product to cart the modal is opened

I tried this code :

```
$('.ajax_add_to_cart_button').click(function()
{
        if($('#layer_cart').css('display') == 'block')
        { 
            var total_product = $('.ajax_block_products_total').text().replace('€', '').replace(',', '.');
            alert(total_product);
        }  
});
```

but this contained the old value, because when I click on the add to cart the modal is not opened so it is set as display none.

Which event could be better to check if the modal is really opened because it takes few second, or milisecond before it is opened, because there is an ajax request to check the cart on the server.

So I don't know which even't could be better to do the action when the modal is opened.

Actually I tried to do it onckicl on the add to cart button but at this time it is not opened so it contain the old value.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: Did you try like ` $('.ajax_add_to_cart_button').on('click', function(){`

Comment: yeah it is the same issue

Comment: Which modal you are using? I thought it's bootstrap but I just see, there is no tag for bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to show the `layer_cart` this will enable you to check for the `display:block` css rule.

Then to update your `total_product` value you'll need a variable which the value gets stored in and you just add the old value and new value together to get the total value.

Check this example below:

```js
var total_product = 0;

$('.ajax_add_to_cart_button').on("click", function()
{

  $('#layer_cart').show();
  
  if($('#layer_cart').css('display') == 'block')
  { 
    total_product += parseInt($('.ajax_block_products_total').text().replace('€', '').replace(',', '.'));
  }  
  
  alert(total_product);
});
```

```css
#layer_cart
{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ajax_add_to_cart_button">Add to cart</div>

<ul id="layer_cart">

</ul>

<div class="ajax_block_products_total">€100</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this but is till keep the old value of the span so I don't know how to get the new value

Comment: your code works fine, but on prestashop it seems there is a request with ajax so the price show is not the samed as in the modal because there is an update, but i don't know how to fix this trouble